# Generating UV coordinates for texture atlas

Tags: sprite-sheet

I'm trying to find a tool which will generate UV coordinates from the texture atlas i have.
For example, if the following is my image
[image]

i need an xml or something which will describe that image like the following
[image]

Is there any tool which will do this ? The tools i found were only creating such xmls ,only after adding individual frame images.
Please correct me if i'm in a wrong notion.

Comment: I don't know of a tool, but you can write it yourself pretty easily (in Excel, if you like).  
  
If there the image is W sprites wide and H sprites high, then the four coordinates for sprite (x,y), 0 <= x < W, 0 <= y < H are made up of:  
<code>
    top = y / H;  
    bottom = (y+1) / H;  
    left = x / W;  
    right = (x+1) / W;  
</code>  
  
where the four coordinates would be (top,left), (top,right), (bottom,left), and (bottom,right).  
  
And then you can export these to xml or comma-delimited or whatever you like.

(sorry about the formatting of this comment.  I really tried)

Comment: That is a an example image. I need a bit generic solution. All of my images are not with uniform separation and dimensions.Actual ones are tightly packed and frames have different dimensions.

Comment: Well, i found the answer here....

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35868/how-to-decompose-sprite-sheet